# ¿Cómo validar la cabecera status y ok de una petición AJAX con la API Fetch?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

Cuando hacemos uso de la API fetch para hacer peticiones tipo AJAX a nuestro backend, generalmente nos queda de este modo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  async function getData()
  {
    let request = fetch('https://example.com/api')
    let respuesta = await request
    let datos = await respuesta.json()

     console.log(datos)
  }

  getData()

</script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo deberiamos verificar como se hacia en `XMLHttpRquest` donde se revisa si el `status` es `200` y el `responseText` donde verificamos si es `OK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para checar estos datos podemos revisar los siguiente**

Dentro de la función, mandamos a imprimir por `console.log()` la variable `respuesta` que en este caso es la que almacena el valor de la respuesta del servidor

```
 async function getData()
  {
    let request = fetch('https://example.com/api')
    let respuesta = await request
    let datos = await respuesta.json()

     console.log(respuesta)
  }

  getData()
```

**Respuesta**

```
[object Response] {
  arrayBuffer: function arrayBuffer() { [native code] },
  blob: function blob() { [native code] },
  body: [object Object] { ... },
  bodyUsed: true,
  clone: function clone() { [native code] },
  formData: function formData() { [native code] },
  headers: [object Headers] {
    append: function append() { [native code] },
    delete: function delete() { [native code] },
    entries: function entries() { [native code] },
    forEach: function forEach() { [native code] },
    get: function get() { [native code] },
    has: function has() { [native code] },
    keys: function keys() { [native code] },
    set: function set() { [native code] },
    values: function values() { [native code] }
  },
  json: function json() { [native code] },
  ok: true,
  redirected: false,
  status: 200,
  statusText: "",
  text: function text() { [native code] },
  type: "cors",
  url: "https://example.com/api"
}
```

**Lo que vamos a revisar**

Nos interesan para este caso las claves: `ok` y `status` con lo cual quedaría validado de este modo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="xml">cargar</button>
  <div id="lienzo"></div>
<script>
  async function getData()
  {
    let request = fetch('https://example.com/api',{
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    let respuesta = await request
    let datos = await respuesta.json()

    if(respuesta.status == 200 && respuesta.ok == true){
       console.log(datos)
    }
  }

  getData()

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que hicimos fue validar en un condicional que: `respuesta.status == 200` y que `respuesta.ok == true`